# Flask-Kerberos yields different results when running the code via "flask run" and with Vim

Tags: python, flask, kerberos

Simply saying there is a Flask App based on the [Flask-Kerberos example](https://github.com/deshaw/flask-kerberos/tree/master/example) with a valid keytab file (`os.environ['KRB5_KTNAME']='/path/to/file.keytab'`).

This is a working tree of my project:

```
flask_kerberos_example\
    static\
        style.css
    templates\
        index.html
    example_pure.py
    config.py
    .flaskenv
```

Here is the content of *'example_pure.py'* file:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask_kerberos import init_kerberos
from flask_kerberos import requires_authentication
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

@app.route("/")
@requires_authentication
def index(user):
    return render_template('index.html', user=user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_kerberos(app, hostname='Server.l.s.d')
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

here is a *'config.py'*

```py
import os
import base64
from dotenv import load_dotenv

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(os.path.join(basedir, '.flaskenv'))

class Config(object):

    # Setup Secret Key for Application
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or str(base64.b64encode('you-will-never-guess'.encode("utf-8")))
```

and here is a *'.flaskenv'*

```py
FLASK_APP="example_pure.py"
FLASK_RUN_HOST="0.0.0.0"
FLASK_RUN_PORT=5000
```

when I execute this code via vim with <kbd>F9</kbd> I am getting the desired output

Browser (`http://Server.l.s.d:5000/`)

> Flask Kerberos Example
>
> It worked, I think you are username@L.S.D

CMD

```
(venv) User@Server:~/.../flask_kerberos_example$ vim

 * Serving Flask app "example_pure" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
a.b.c.d - - [08/Jul/2021 09:35:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 -
a.b.c.d - - [08/Jul/2021 09:35:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
a.b.c.d - - [08/Jul/2021 09:35:19] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

However, when I start the Flask applciation with `flask run` I don't see exactly the same result.

Browser (`http://Server.l.s.d:5000/`)

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
> your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in
> the application.

CMD

```
(venv) User@Server:~/.../flask_kerberos_example$ flask run

 * Serving Flask app "example_pure.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
a.b.c.d - - [08/Jul/2021 09:37:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 -
[2021-07-08 09:37:28,023] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_kerberos.py", line 106, in decorated
    rc = _gssapi_authenticate(token)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_kerberos.py", line 70, in _gssapi_authenticate
    rc, state = kerberos.authGSSServerInit(_SERVICE_NAME)
TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not None
a.b.c.d - - [08/Jul/2021 09:37:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

As I can see that Flask scolds about the `_SERVICE_NAME` variable. I do not understand if I have to set it either in *'.flaskenv'* or *'config.py'*, do not I? It looks like this problem partially overlaps with my previous question: ["TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not None" when running Flask-Kerberos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68112391/typeerror-argument-1-must-be-str-not-none-when-running-flask-kerberos)

Can somebody explain to me what could a problem and why am I getting different results?

Comment: could you post your app directory tree so we can see all the path to files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `flask run`, it *imports* your app as a module, therefore `__name__` will not be equal to "__main__", therefore `init_kerberos()` never gets called and never sets the `_SERVICE_NAME` global within flask-kerberos.

Also, generally, I would suggest switching to [flask-gssapi](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-GSSAPI/), both because it is written in a cleaner manner and does not rely on global state, and because it is based on python-gssapi instead of the old & nearly unmaintained pykerberos.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed `flask-gssapi` look much more promising to me, e.g. I do not need *Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0* when installing it, in comparison with pykerberos, flask-kerberos, wsgi-kerberos...

Comment: Oh, you're writing this on Windows? You _might_ still need it, as Windows uses SSPI which is slightly different from GSSAPI. (How come all your posts show Linux paths though? I can't imagine needing Visual C++ to build any Linux software, even if it is for WSL.)

Comment: It is a bit painful story. I stared on Windows, however I could not install flask-kerberos(pykerberos) due to *"Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0"* license issue.
So, I had to migrate to Debian Server (a Server that hosts my API and Web Application) which includes those builds.
But since flask-gssapi can be installed on Windows (Did it today *"Successfully installed decorator-5.0.9 flask-gssapi-1.5.0 gssapi-1.6.14"*) I can continue developing on Windows (on Debian there is not PyCharm, just vim and nano), do not I?

Comment: I'm fairly sure PyCharm is available for Debian. (So is VSCode, Sublime, Geany, IDEA, KDevelop, gnome-builder, Eclipse, Emacs, and other editors.)

Comment: You are correct, but I am accessing it via PuTTY, so I do not have GUI just pure cmd :) (And I am not yet powerful in development ... learning by doing)